# negative ack from socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io to send data from my sever to clients. There are situations when a client looses its connection but the server gets to know about this only when the next heartbeat is not recieved from the ckient.

the messages that are sent between the client loosing its network connection to the time when the sever derives this from absense of heartbeats are lost and I am not able resend them when the client rconnects.

I know there I can send a callback in my message which the client will call on successfull delivey of message. however this callback is asynchronous and I Am not aware of any way by which I can getto know that the message delivery failed. Can anyone please help me findhow can I capture a failure to delive a message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the callback being asynchronous effect the solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO), you can configure "max reconnection attempts" for

> How many times should Socket.IO attempt to reconnect with the server after a a dropped connection. After this we will emit the reconnect_failed event.